# How To Move awscli contents to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, gitlab-ci, aws-cli

Below is the output from Gitlab console,now what I would like is to move all contents of folder Jun-06-1560275587 including folder name Jun-06-1560275587to MongoDB ,my question is how do i configure mongodb to talk to awscli console of Gitlab and then push the folder contents to MongoDB

I am using AWS With Gitlab

```
$ aws s3 cp  s3://${BUCKET_NAME}/${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} s3://${BUCKET_NAME}/PreviousExecuted/$(date +"%h-%m-%s") --        recursive --include "binaries/${filename}*"
Completed 108.5 KiB/83.7 MiB (240.2 KiB/s) with 359 file(s) remaining
copy: s3://gitlabgatlingreport/master/index.html to s3://gitlabgatlingreport/PreviousExecuted/Jun-06-        1560275587/index.html
Completed 108.5 KiB/83.7 MiB (240.2 KiB/s) with 358 file(s) remaining
Completed 140.1 KiB/83.7 MiB (294.6 KiB/s) with 358 file(s) remaining
copy: s3://gitlabgatlingreport/master/js/moment.min.js to s3://gitlabgatlingreport/PreviousExecuted/Jun-06-        1560275587/js/moment.min.js
Completed 140.1 KiB/83.7 MiB (294.6 KiB/s) with 357 file(s) remaining
Completed 140.2 KiB/83.7 MiB (286.9 KiB/s) with 357 file(s) remaining
copy: s3://gitlabgatlingreport/master/js/assertions.xml to s3://gitlabgatlingreport/PreviousExecuted/Jun-06-        1560275587/js/assertions.xml
Completed 140.2 KiB/83.7 MiB (286.9 KiB/s) with 356 file(s) remaining
Completed 153.3 KiB/83.7 MiB (309.9 KiB/s) with 356 file(s) remaining
copy: s3://gitlabgatlingreport/master/js/all_sessions.js to s3://gitlabgatlingreport/PreviousExecuted/Jun-06-        1560275587/js/all_sessions.js
Completed 153.3 KiB/83.7 MiB (309.9 KiB/s) with 355 file(s) remaining
Completed 156.9 KiB/83.7 MiB (311.0 KiB/s) with 355 file(s) remaining
copy: s3://gitlabgatlingreport/master/js/gatling.js to 
s3://gitlabgatlingreport/PreviousExecuted/Jun-06-        
1560275587/js/gatling.js
```

I need to move all contents of folder Jun-06-1560275587 including folder name Jun-06-1560275587 from gitlab awscli to MongoDB

Here is my Gitlab yaml,do let me know if i need to add some MongoDB image in my Gitlab yaml so that mongoDB and gitlab awscli can interconnect with each other

```
displayresults:
image: python:latest
stage: displayresults
tags:
  - docker
dependencies:
  - cleanup
before_script:
- pip install awscli # Install the SDK
script:
 - 'find /builds/LOT/perftestsgeneric'
 - 'find binaries'
 - 'cd /builds/LOT/perftestsgeneric/binaries/${filename}* && ls && hostname -i'  - 'aws s3 cp     /builds/LOT/perftestsgeneric/binaries/${filename}* s3://${BUCKET_NAME}/${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} --recursive' # Replace     example-bucket with your bucket
- 'aws s3 cp  s3://${BUCKET_NAME}/${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} s3://${BUCKET_NAME}/PreviousExecuted/$(date +"%h-%m-%s") --    recursive --include "binaries/${filename}*"'
environment:
  name: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  url: http://${BUCKET_NAME}.s3-website.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}  # This is the url of       the bucket we saved before
on_stop: clean_s3 # When the branch is merged, we clean up after ourself

clean_s3:
image: "python:latest"
stage: displayresults
tags:
  - docker
before_script:
 - pip install awscli
script:
 - aws s3 rm s3://${BUCKET_NAME}/${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} --recursive # 
Replace example-bucket with your bucket
environment:
  name: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  action: stop
 when: manual
```